# HTML подключение внешнего стиля css

Tags: html, css, html5

Не находит файл стиля, что не так?

Как выглядит html:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style_1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ptr">Hello world</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.ptr{
    color: red;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `./css/style.css`. И ещё в `<DOCTYPE HTML>` поставьте `!`.

Comment: Пробовал разные пути прописывать

Comment: @entithat мы что, гадалки? Есть правила написания пути.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ну всякое бывает.. попробовал так - не получилось, попробовал так - вышло.. Честно говоря, что есть правила, что нету правил..

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полный путь к этой странице и полный путь к css файлу - такой, что если Вы напечатаете его в адресной строке браузера, css файл загрузится

Comment: Все файлы находятся в папке project, в ней две папки одна css другая pattern, в файле html папки pattern прописываю путь до css/style.css

Comment: `../css/style.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Все файлы находятся в папке project, в ней две папки одна css другая
>   pattern, в файле html папки pattern прописываю путь до css/style.css

Переходим в папку `css` через родительскую:

```
href="../css/style_1.css"
```